# Does erudite carry positive or negative or neutral connotation?

Tags: connotation

Does erudite carry positive or negative or neutral connotation?

I received [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112150/equi-convergence-of-a-function-family-at-a-point#comment261543_112150) on my writing style from a mathematician a while ago

> Why not try for direct active voice and stop trying to make it sound erudite?

Comment: I'm guessing that the comment in the linked post was trying to communicate that since you were writing about math, writing clearly was much, much more important than injecting your voice or sounding pretty.

Comment: According to OED, this word is now commonly used (as in this case) in a sarcastic sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an entirely positive word. An attempt to sound affectedly erudite, on the other hand -- that is bad.

Comment: Does everyone have to sound affectedly erudite, before they are really erudite?

Comment: Well... No. You can simply not be conscious of your voice, and perhaps your erudition will shine through naturally.

Comment: +1 I concur.  If one were attempting "to sound affectedly erudite," I would instead refer to that person as being [pedantic.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedantic)  Merriam-Webster's definition is my personal favorite: ostentatiously learned.

Comment: Frederick Winsor spoke of an _Erudite Verbal Haze_ in his poem "The Theory that Jack Built" that appeared in [The Space-Child's Mother Goose](http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~hsg/134/poems/space-childs-mother-goose.txt) (1958). It suggested obfuscation, and so wasn't entirely positive.

Comment: Likewise trying to catch a bullet in your teeth is quite different to actually catching a bullet in your teeth, in consequences and entertainment value.